# trying to do a REST web service using PUT in objective c (iphone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been trying to do a REST web service using PUT in iphone for days but with no luck. i'm wondering if anyone can upload a sample of doing REST web service using PUT or the approach to do? it will be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ASIHTTPRequest. Read the [**PUT requests and custom POSTs** section in the overview](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).